# Excel VBA - Object Required

Tags: vba, excel

I haven't had to use Excel VBA in awhile, but I decided to dig it up to build a few user-friendly and accessible templates for tracking monthly shipments.

This specific search function is giving me a headache and I suspect it's because I'm quite rusty with the syntax.

I've got myself to this point where I'm receiving an 'object required' error when calling a user form but from what I can see from stepping through, I've explicitly declared and defined everything related to the problem line.

Appreciate any help/refreshers. My face eagerly awaits my palm.

Edit: Current working code posted in response below

Full code

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
'Clear result message
Me.rResult.caption = ""

'BOL (cached)
Dim BOL As Range
Set BOL = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Values").Range("$A$3")
'Addresses (cached)
Dim addr As Range
Set addr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Values").Range("$A$4:$D$21")
Dim i As Range
'Search Range
Dim srange As Range
'Target Range
Dim trange As Range
'First result
Dim fr As Range
'Result counter
Dim c As Integer
c = 0

With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    'Set search range
    Set srange = .Range(.Cells(7, 6), _
    .Cells(.Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row, _
    .Cells(6, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column))

    'Find search results in search range
    Set trange = srange.Find(BOL.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
    'If the cell is not empty and the header in row 6 has a value of "BOL"
    If Not trange.Value Is Nothing Then '***Problem Line***
        If .Cells(6, trange.Value).Value = "BOL" Then
        'set first address
        Set fr = .Range(trange.Address)
        Do
            'result counter
            c = c + 1
            'save each address within cache range
            For Each i In addr
                If i.Value = "" Then i.Value = trange.Address
            Next i
            Set trange = trange.FindNext(trange)
        Loop While Not trange Is Nothing And trange.Address <> fr.Address
        End If
    End If
End With

'Select the first address
If c <> 0 Then fr.Select

'Result message
Me.rResult.caption = "Search found " & c & _
    " result(s) for BOL: " & BOL.Value & "."

'clear cached BOL
BOL.Clear

End Sub
```

Comment: `My face eagerly awaits my palm.` +1 Edit: which line throws error?

Comment: @findwindow probably the one with the comment saying `'****This is the line that throws the error.****` ;) .

Comment: @VincentG thanks but one, too lazy to read through it (OP should always identify it in question). Two, didn't see it because it's past the scroll (see point one ^_^).

Comment: You don't test the result of the return of your `srange.Find()`. If it fails to find anything trange will be Nothing and trange.Value will fail.

Comment: @VincentG where's `srange.Find()`? `Set srange = .Range(...`

Comment: @VincentG oh, you mean `.Cells(6, trange.Value).Value`. Yea, OP, you tested that on same line as `If Not trange.Value Is Nothing`.

Comment: I'll make the edit to the OP now. Edit: misunderstood. I've split the line into two IF's, and it still seems to be throwing the error.

Comment: @findwindow two lines above the line that give error.

Comment: Yea, what Jason said below. Remove the `.value`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's your .value at the end of trange. When you do a find and nothing is found then the trange comes back as nothing. Then you are asking for the value of nothing, which is giving you the object required error.

Just change it to `If Not trange Is Nothing...` but I think @Abe Gold is right, you'll need two if statements. Because you can't check '.cells(6, trange.value).value = "BOM"` if trange is nothing.

Should look like this for your if statement (Taken from @Abe Gold code above)

```
If Not trange Is Nothing Then
    If .Cells(6, trange.Value).Value = "BOL" Then 
      'set first address
      Set fr = .Range(trange.Address)
      Do
        'result counter
         c = c + 1
        'save each address within cache range
        For Each i In addr
            If i.Value = "" Then i.Value = trange.Address
        Next i
        Set trange = trange.FindNext(trange)
     Loop While trange.Address <> fr.Address
   End IF
End If
```

Comment: I've been testing with mock data, so I know that trange is populated.
However, I removed the .value and it seems to work so go figure.

Comment: Yep, there's a definitely handprint on my face. I removed the .value from the first IF and when I looked at the 2nd IF, I realized I had used "trange.value" instead of "trange.column" to check the header above. Problem fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Another change.

```
If Not trange.Value Is Nothing Then
```

should be

```
If Not trange Is Nothing Then
```

Rewrite your IF into two IFs:

```
 If Not trange.Value Is Nothing Then
        If .Cells(6, trange.Value).Value = "BOL" Then 
          'set first address
          Set fr = .Range(trange.Address)
          Do
            'result counter
             c = c + 1
            'save each address within cache range
            For Each i In addr
                If i.Value = "" Then i.Value = trange.Address
            Next i
            Set trange = trange.FindNext(trange)
         Loop While trange.Address <> fr.Address
       End IF
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

I know there is both an accepted answer and two most upvoted ones, but I'm both proposing improvements and mainly **missing something** (see last point)

please consider this code:

```
'Find search results in search range
Set trange = srange.Find(BOL.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False) '<~~always specify those parameters since they are saved from any Find() usage, even that from UI
If Not trange Is Nothing Then 'If the cell is not empty and the header in row 6 has a value of "BOL"
    If .Cells(6, trange.Column).Value = "BOL" Then
        Set fr = trange '<~~store first trange occurrence found
        Do
            c = c + 1 'update result counter
            addr.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) = trange.Address '<~~save current address within cache range
            Set trange = srange.FindNext(trange) '<~~search next occurrence of trange in srange
        Loop While Not trange.Address <> fr.Address
    End If
End If
```

whose differences from the OP's one are hereby summarized:

- `Set trange = srange.Find(BOL.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)`

  always specify those parameters since they are saved from any `Find()` usage, even that from UI, so that yo may find yourself involuntarily looking at string Part and/or minding Case Matching
- `If Not trange Is Nothing Then`

  ok, that has already been established by all answers and comments
- `Set fr = trange`

  since `.Range(trange.Address)` is redundant
- `addr.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) = trange.Address`

  instead of the `For Each i In addr` loop
- `Set trange = srange.FindNext(trange)`

  **here there was `Set trange = trange FindNext(trange)`**

  shouldn't the second `trange` be `srange`?

Comment: I did not know that UI find settings affected the find method, but it definitely makes sense. Thanks!

I cleaned up the code a bit more after we solved the issue and caught the redundancy and the findnext mistake. :)

As for the SpecialCells, the purpose of the for loop is to find an empty cell within addr range to cache the address. Correct me if I'm wrong, but shouldn't xlCellTypeConstants be xlCelltypeBlanks? And I think specialcells select ALL cells meeting the type criteria within range, whereas I'm looking for a single cell to fill.

Comment: thank you for feedback. 1) yes, to select empty cells use `xlCellTypeBlanks` parameter instead of `xlCellTypeConstants` for `SpecialCells` method 2) `SpecialCells` method returns ALL (blank, if with `xlCellTypeBlanks` parameter) cells of the `range` he's called onto, so `addr.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) = trange.Address` would fill ALL blank cells of `addr` `range` with `trange.Address`. which is precisely what your `For Each i In addr` loop did.  3) How could previous solutions work with that `Set trange = trange FindNext(trange)` statement (and with the `Find()` saved parameters issue)?

Comment: This is my mistake. I missed an `Exit For` in the original version of the loop. A careless oversight. I fixed that at some point early on after posting, as I saw that the cache was being filled with the first address. I caught and fixed the `FindNext` issue as soon as I stepped through the code and passed the IF statements error free. The saved parameters didn't affect my search tool as I hadn't performed a search with different parameters while troubleshooting. Definitely a good tip going forward though. I'll add the current version of the code in a separate response.

Comment: well, from your last post you also found out you needed the `If .Cells(6, trange.Column).Value = "BOL" Then` check inside the `Do-Loop` rather then outside it....

Answer (score 0):

This `If` statement was only being applied to the first found address. I moved it into the loop to be applied to every iterative result.

```
If .Cells(6, trange.Column).Value = "BOL" Then
```

Added a number of other changes/fixes outlined in above responses. Thanks!

Current working code snip:

```
'Find search results in search range
Set trange = srange.Find(BOL.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
'If the cell is not empy and the header in row 6 has a value of "BOL"
If Not trange Is Nothing Then
    'set first address
    Set fr = trange
    Do
        If .Cells(6, trange.Column).Value = "BOL" Then
        'result counter
        c = c + 1
        'save each address within cache range
        For Each i In addr
            If i.Value = "" Then
                i.Value = trange.Address
                Exit For
            End If
        Next i
        End If
    Set trange = srange.FindNext(trange)
    Loop While Not trange Is Nothing And trange.Address <> fr.Address
End If
```

Comment: you can omit the `...Not trange Is Nothing ...` part in the `Loop While` ending condition since 1) the `Loop` begins only after `If Not trange Is Nothing` check passing 2) at every iteration `trange` is set to `srange.FindNext(trange)` which can _never_ be Nothing since `FindNext` would always find a `BOL.Value` occurrence in `srange` range, caught in a circular loop inside it. from which the necessary check on the "first address" to end the loop

Comment: Yep, I just left it in there cause I figured it wasn't hurting anyone, but for the sake of transparency, I'll remove it.